# How to prevent JPA from rolling back transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, struts

Methods invoked:
1. Struts Action
2. Service class method (annotated by @Transactional)
3. Xfire webservice call

Everything including struts (DelegatingActionProxy) and transactions is configured with Spring.

Persistence is done with JPA/Hibernate.

Sometimes the webservice will throw an unchecked exception. I catch this exception and throw a checked exception. I don't want the transaction to roll back since the web service exception changes the current state. I have annotated the method like this:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={XFireRuntimeException.class, Exception.class})
public ActionForward callWS(Order order, ....) throws Exception
  (...)
  OrderResult orderResult = null;

  try {
    orderResult = webService.order(product, user)
  } catch (XFireRuntimeException xfireRuntimeException) {
    order.setFailed(true);
    throw new WebServiceOrderFailed(order);
  } finally {
    persist(order);
  }
}
```

I still get this exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

When I try to reproduce this with junit, the transaction isn't marked for roll back and it's still possible to commit the transaction.

How do I make Spring not to roll back the transaction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Managed to create a test case for this problem:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:web/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml",
        "file:web/WEB-INF/spring/services.xml"})
@Transactional
public class DoNotRollBackTest {
    @Autowired FakeService fakeService;

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void testRunXFireException() {
        fakeService.doSomeTransactionalStuff();
    }
}
```

FakeService:

```
@Service
public class FakeService {
    @Autowired private EcomService ecomService;
    @Autowired private WebService webService;

    @Transactional(noRollbackFor={XFireRuntimeException.class})
    public void doSomeTransactionalStuff() {
        Order order = ecomService.findOrderById(459);

        try {
            webService.letsThrowAnException();
        } catch (XFireRuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Caugh XFireRuntimeException:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        order.setBookingType(BookingType.CAR_BOOKING);
        ecomService.persist(order);
    }
}
```

WebService:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class WebService {
    public void letsThrowAnException() {
        throw new XFireRuntimeException("test!");
    }
}
```

This will recreate the rollback-exception.

Then I realized that the transaction is probably being marked as rollbackOnly in WebService.letsThrowAnException since WebService is also transactional. I moved to annotation:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={XFireRuntimeException.class})
    public void letsThrowAnException() {
```

Now the transaction isn't being rolled back and I can commit the changes to Order.

Answer (score 3):

You must not throw an exception where Spring can see it. In this case, you must not throw `WebServiceOrderFailed()`. The solution is to split the code into two methods. The first method does the error handling and returns the exception, the outer method creates the transaction.

[EDIT] As for `noRollbackFor`: Try to replace `Exception.class` with `WebServiceOrderFailed.class`.

Comment: This is incorrect. `noRollbackFor` checks specified exception class and all its subclasses: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#noRollbackFor()

Additionally, by default checked exceptions will NOT trigger the rollback: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings

Comment: This doesn't explain why the code above rolls back on `WebServiceOrderFailed`.

Comment: My guess is that WebServiceOrderFailed is a RuntimeException and the code above (`noRollbackFor={..., Exception.class}`) can't have any effect since Exception is handled specially (otherwise, the inheritance code would also ignore RuntimeException since it extends Exception).

Comment: Thanks for your input. You guys pointed me in the right direction! (WebServiceOrderFailed extends Exception, it's a checked exception)

Comment: Kindly help as I face the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343137/problem-in-handling-unit-of-work-using-hibernate-jpa