# jpa transaction stop rollback

Tags: spring, jpa

I have the following code. I want the execution to continue even if there is an exception

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={PersistenceException.class, PSQLException.class,SQLGrammarException.class})
public void executeQuery(String parameterName){
    Query query = objectManager.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SOME UPDATE QUERY");

    Map<String, String> paramMap = (Map) destTableMap.get(parameterName);
    query.setParameter("xyz",5);

    try{
        query.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The exception stack trace that I receive is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:476)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at 
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701750/how-to-prevent-jpa-from-rolling-back-transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions):

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException,
>   immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close()
>   and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not
>   leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by
>   Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the Session will
>   be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

The transaction **must** be rolled back. So, if you want to continue executing if Hibernate throws an exception, you should put the execute the `executeQuery` method in its own transaction, using the REQUIRES_NEW propagation in the `@Transactional` annotation. This way, only this short transaction will be rolled back.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use the following to avoid this `TransactionSystemException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction;` nested exception is `javax.persistence.RollbackException`: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public String foo(Object obj, String tableName, BindingResult result) throws Exception
{
    // put some code here
}
```